# Run boost library with borland compiler 5.82

Tags: c++, boost, borland-c++

I am trying to run the "getting started" example:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

after downloading the boost library to my machine. But I can't get it running.
After googling, all I found is to add:

```
#define BOOST_REGEX_USE_VCL
#define BOOST_NO_OPERATORS_IN_NAMESPACE
#define BOOST_NO_STD_LOCALE
```

That still didn't help. The error is:

```
[C++ Error] lambda_traits.hpp(435): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'bind_traits<R>'
[C++ Error] lambda_traits.hpp(389): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'bind_traits<R>'
```

Anybody any (further) ideas? As stated in the headline I'm running with the 5.82 version of the Borland compiler.

Oh...and please don't suggest to use another compiler. I'm at work, and I'm not my own boss. :-/

;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think boost::lambda doesn't work with 5.8.2 - It may not even work with the very latest C++Builder compiler.

Have a look at the results on the [bcbboost](http://bcbboost.sourceforge.net/test/1_35_0/cs-win32.html) pages, and keep an eye on [David Dean's blog.](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ddean/2009/09/23/34847)

Comment: If I get this message: C:\>bcc32.exe [RETURN] | Borland C++ 5.82 for Win32 Copyright (c) 1993, 2005 Borland | ... I am running with the borland compiler 5.8.2?

Comment: Yes. They're the same. Not sure where the "5.8.2" notation comes from.

Comment: boost::lambda does not work with any shipping version of bcc. There won't be any new information on my blog, since I am no longer working at Embarcadero.

Comment: @David Dean: If I spent more time on the forums I would have spotted that! Sorry to hear you've gone, and all the best with your new role. The effort you put into BCB QC was phenomenal, and much appreciated.

Comment: @david wow, sorry to hear that :/ So who's going to be taking over that role now?

Comment: @victor It looks like Bruneau is picking up the slack in the forums lately. There are a bunch of great guys there that should be able to pick up the baton.